Google Drive Api File ThumbnailLink SOMETIMES omits Access-Control-Allow-Origin: header
I know what CORS is, I know that there are similar questions about this problem, but none of the solutions cover my app's behaviour. Bear with me.
My Flutter web app uses the Google Drive API to upload images to the appDataFolder. All the relevant code is this:

final scopes = [DriveApi.driveAppdataScope];

class DriveServiceApi {
  DriveServiceApi();

  Future<auth.AuthClient> getClient() async {
    final client = await googleSignIn.authenticatedClient();
    if (client == null) {
      throw Exception('Client is null');
    }
    return client;
  }

  Future<List<Token>> fetchTokens() async {
    final isAuthorised = await googleSignIn.canAccessScopes(scopes);
    if (!isAuthorised) {
      await googleSignIn.requestScopes(scopes);
    }
    final client = await getClient();
    final api = DriveApi(client);

    final files = await api.files.list(
      spaces: 'appDataFolder',
      $fields:
          'files(id, name, properties, appProperties, webContentLink, thumbnailLink, createdTime, modifiedTime)',
    );
    return files.files!.map((file) {
      if (file.thumbnailLink != null) {
        file.thumbnailLink = file.thumbnailLink!.replaceAll('=s220', '=s300');
      }
      return Token(
        file: file,
        metadata: const TokenMetadata(),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  Future<Token> addToken(XFile image) async {
    final client = await getClient();
    final api = DriveApi(client);
    final extension = image.path.split('.').last;
    return api.files
        .create(
      File(
        name: 'token_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}',
        parents: ['appDataFolder'],
      ),
      $fields:
          'id, name, properties, appProperties, webContentLink, thumbnailLink, createdTime, modifiedTime',
      uploadMedia:
          Media(image.openRead(), null, contentType: 'image/$extension'),
      uploadOptions: ResumableUploadOptions(
        numberOfAttempts: 5,
      ),
    )
        .then((file) {
          debugPrint("Uploaded File ID: ${file.id}");
      return Token(
        file: file,
        metadata: TokenMetadata.fromJson(file.properties ?? {}),
      );
    });
  }

  Future<bool> deleteToken(Token token) async {
    final client = await getClient();
    final api = DriveApi(client);
    return api.files
        .delete(token.file.id!)
        .then((_) => true)
        .catchError((_) => false);
  }
}

My app shows the thumbnails of the uploaded images, but this sometimes results in CORS issues. The image below shows three such images. The one on the left is fetched successfully. The DevTools show the headers, and it clearly shows Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.

For the other two images, both the UI and the DevTools show that something has gone wrong. It appears that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not sent along:

I have a refresh button that calls the fetchTokens function again ('Token' is the name of my 'product'; it has nothing to do with access tokens or anything). Pressing it fetches the images in the appDatafolder again and rerenders the thumbnails. Doing so results in a new subset of images failing:

I would say every thumbnail has about a 50% chance of not sending along the correct CORS headers. I cannot imagine this is intended behaviour, but I also cannot find any explanation as to why this happens. It cannot be that access has expired, because re-fetching the images may end up correctly showing an image that was not showing before. What is going on here?

Is there an age difference? Like in: files created earlier or copied/shared from other google accounts behave differently?

@sehe no, that does not matter; it happens to all images, regardless of when they are uploaded. Newly uploaded ones will show the same behaviour. Note that all images are uploaded by the same user and to the same folder, with the same permissions.
